# What type i can use for a ReactBootstrap form's submit event other than any in typescript. What can i use in place of **any** in argument type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-bootstrap

I was submitting a React-Bootstrap form with validation. My code is working fine when is use

```
  const submitHandler = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = e.currentTarget!;
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
    setValidated(true);
    email &&
      !checkMailSuccess &&
      dispatch(checkMailActions.checkMailStart(email.trim()));
    if (
      validated === true &&
      form.checkValidity() === true &&
      isExist === false
    ) {
      dispatch(
        credentialsActions.saveStart({
          name: name.trim(),
          dob: dob.trim(),
          fatherName: fatherName.trim(),
          address: address.trim(),
          docType: docType.trim(),
          docNum: docNum.trim(),
          email: email.trim(),
          image: image.trim(),
        })
      );
      navigate('/step2');
    }
  };
```

but i want proper type of event **e** could anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be a `Form Event` only. If you are using any editor you will have access to the `React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>` type.
If you type like this, even this should work:

```
const submitHandler = (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
```

Or you have the option to add type to the event handler itself and rest will be taken care of.

```
const submitHandler : React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = (e) => {
....
```

[Link](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forms_and_events/)

**Tip:**
If you have a decent editor, just hover over stuff to get hints.

[image]

Comment: I already know aboyt React.FormEvent and SyntheticEvent and tried them already but they are of no help. They don't include type definaton of **checkValidity()**  also i am working on Form element from react-bootstrap not simple html form

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, event.currentTarget.checkValidity method not on the event type - according to this page if you inline the callback function the typing works

https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forms_and_events/

and that does appear to work in my tests. Hovering the mouse over the event param of the callback function in VS code I get the type

```
React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>
```

which does seem to work